# Switch between the view data table and the highcharts graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a two High Charts. I'm implementing the export and download and switch between pie and bar chart, but I have two problems here:

1. When I switch from the bar to pie chart it's not working.
2. When I click on view, data table chart should be hidden and the table has to show in the place of chart.

[please find the code here on jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/GnanaSagar/psnh87ud/16/)

```
[1][:https://jsfiddle.net/GnanaSagar/psnh87ud/16/][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have only one series if you use `pie` chart type. The best way to change `pie` chart to `bar` chart is to connect all data to one series or use different chart type.

```
series: [{
    legendType: 'point',
    name: 'Tokyo',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        x: -0.2,
        y: 10,
        name: 'A'
    }, {
        x: 0.2,
        y: 20,
        name: 'B'
    }, {
        x: 0.8,
        y: 25,
        name: 'C'
    }, {
        x: 1.2,
        y: 20,
        name: 'D'
    }, {
        x: 1.8,
        y: 10,
        name: 'E'
    }, {
        x: 2.2,
        y: 20,
        name: 'F'
    }]
}]
```

To toggle the data table:

```
$('#viewDataTable').click(function() {
    var chart = Highcharts.charts[0],
        chartDiv = $(chart.renderTo);

    if (chartDiv.is(":visible")) {
        chartDiv.hide();
        if (!chart.dataTableDiv) {

            chart.update({
                exporting: {
                    showTable: true
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(chart.dataTableDiv).show();
        }
    } else {
        chartDiv.show();
        $(chart.dataTableDiv).hide();
    }
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zL0agnwt/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.showTable

Comment: HI, @ppotaczek  what about i have a page of charts like this and i want to switch between the chart and the data table

Comment: Hi @Gnana, It looks like that your porblem is already resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54743448/switch-between-chart-and-datatable-in-highcharts