# Switch between chart and datatable in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

im working on switch between the highchart, i have written some code but it doesnt work when i click on switch above the particular chart should replace the chart with datatable.

JsFiddle Link: jsfiddle.net/GnanaSagar/psnh87ud/61/

Html file with js code used:

```js
function switchToDataTable(id) {
  var chart = $('#' + id).Highchart(),
    chartDiv = $(chart.renderTo);
  if (chartDiv.is(":visible")) {
    chartDiv.hide();
    if (!chart.dataTableDiv) {
      chart.update({
        exporting: {
          showTable: true
        }
      });
    } else {
      $(chart.dataTableDiv).show();
    }
  } else {
    chartDiv.show();
    $(chart.dataTableDiv).hide();
  }

}

Highcharts.chart('chart1', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      'Jan',
      'Feb',
      'Mar',
      'Apr',
      'May',
      'Jun',
      'Jul',
      'Aug',
      'Sep',
      'Oct',
      'Nov',
      'Dec'
    ],
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

  }, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

  }, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

  }, {
    name: 'Berlin',
    data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

  }]
});

Highcharts.chart('chart2', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      showInLegend: true
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    legendType: 'point',
    data: [{
      name: 'Chrome',
      y: 61.41,
      sliced: true,
      selected: true
    }, {
      name: 'Internet Explorer',
      y: 11.84
    }, {
      name: 'Firefox',
      y: 10.85
    }, {
      name: 'Edge',
      y: 4.67
    }, {
      name: 'Safari',
      y: 4.18
    }, {
      name: 'Other',
      y: 7.05
    }]
  }]
});


Highcharts.chart('chart3', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      showInLegend: true
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    legendType: 'point',
    data: [{
      name: 'Chrome',
      y: 61.41,
      sliced: true,
      selected: true
    }, {
      name: 'Internet Explorer',
      y: 11.84
    }, {
      name: 'Firefox',
      y: 10.85
    }, {
      name: 'Edge',
      y: 4.67
    }, {
      name: 'Safari',
      y: 4.18
    }, {
      name: 'Other',
      y: 7.05
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/7.0.2/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="panel">
    <button onclick="switchToDataTable('chart1')">Switch</button>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="chart1" style="height: 342px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="panel">
    <button onclick="switchToDataTable('chart2')">Switch</button>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="chart2" style="height: 342px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="panel">
    <button onclick="switchToDataTable('chart3')">Switch</button>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="chart3" style="height: 342px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

im working on switch between the highchart, i have wrote some code but it didnt working when i click on switch above the perticular chart should replace the chart with  datatable.

Comment: Please include your code in the question (you can use JS snippets, they work like JSfiddle).

Comment: The full content of your question must be in your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to create one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're fetching the chart is wrong.

You should replace this:

```
var chart = $('#'+id).Highchart()
```

With this:

```
var chart = $("#" + id).highcharts();
```

Comment: THanks for the response man,its not working i have replaced it but no use

Comment: Did you replace it in `switchToDataTable`? I tried and it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/ovL796dw/